# .Net Else Statement

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (username.Text == "test" && password.Text == "test")
        Response.Cookies ["TheCookie"]["Username"] = username.Text;
        Response.Redirect("loggedIn.aspx");
    else
        Label1.Text = "Invalid Username and/or Password.";
}
```

Above is a function I'm trying to make happen. For some reason the else statement here isn't being accepted. I don't know why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have more than one statement on an if branch then you need an enclosing block, `{}`.

Comment: Read the error message; it tells you rather specifically what the problem is.  You should also always be including the relevant error message when asking others for help, rather than just saying that it doesn't work without explanation.

Comment: Whitespace is ignored. Your indentation is misleading: Your `Response.Redirect` is not enclosed in the `if`, and your `else` is senseless.

Answer (score 6):

```
if (username.Text == "test" && password.Text == "test")
{
    Response.Cookies ["TheCookie"]["Username"] = username.Text;
    Response.Redirect("loggedIn.aspx");
}
else
    Label1.Text = "Invalid Username and/or Password.";
```

Wrap it with braces, otherwise it'll take only the next immediate line (statement) as part of the condition.

It's a good practice to do that even for a one line `if/else` because it makes maintenance easier.

```
else
{
    Label1.Text = "Invalid Username and/or Password.";
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice. The asker won't learn from just a code block. Also please note that "caused by a typo" is an official close reason on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

[if-else (C# Reference) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx)

> Both the then-statement and the else-statement can consist of a single
>   statement or **multiple statements that are enclosed in braces**
>   (`{}`). For a single statement, the braces are optional but
>   recommended.

You have multiple statements in the `then` (true) part of if statement. Although you have used indentation, but those spaces/indents will not be considered by the compiler. Since you haven't specified `{}` to define **scope of if statement**, only a single statement is considered for `if` scope. Hence the error.

You can fix that by introducing scope with `{}`. It is also recommended to use `{}` *(explicitly define scope)* for single statement , as it makes code easier to understand and less prone to error. You code should be:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (username.Text == "test" && password.Text == "test")
    {
        Response.Cookies["TheCookie"]["Username"] = username.Text;
        Response.Redirect("loggedIn.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Invalid Username and/or Password.";
    }
}
```